# Origin of the names Python and Idle

Tags: python, python-idle

I have noticed that Python's GUI is called Idle. On the other hand, Eric Idle
was a member of Monty Python. Is this just a coincidence?

Comment: It is not a coincidence.  It was intentional.  Python is named for Monty Python.  Similarly IDLE.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etymology and learned allusions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the name python, there are somewhat official answers in the FAQs:

[Why is it called Python?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/general.html#why-is-it-called-python)

> When he began implementing Python, Guido van
>   Rossum was also reading the published scripts from “Monty Python’s
>   Flying Circus”, a BBC comedy series from the 1970s. Van Rossum thought
>   he needed a name that was short, unique, and slightly mysterious, so
>   he decided to call the language Python.

[Do I have to like “Monty Python’s Flying Circus”?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/general.html#do-i-have-to-like-monty-python-s-flying-circus)

> No, but it helps. :)

Now, as for the name IDLE - according to Guido, the name stands for **Integrated DeveLopment Environment** ([source](http://lwn.net/1999/0114/a/idle.html)).  No doubt, it is also a reference to [Eric Idle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Idle) as well, but I can't find a source for this just now.

Considering all the other references scattered around (for example, python eggs and wheels, pypi cheese shop to name a few), the IDLE name is also a reference - as an [acronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) it seems a little forced.

Comment: Also mentioned in [Python for Dummies](http://books.google.nl/books?id=QhJ8paNWShUC&pg=PT48&lpg=PT48&dq=guido+van+rossum+eric+idle&source=bl&ots=xutTsRaPM3&sig=QQNicliNoIvdpzG4RnmrW2rfLKE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QVnzUqqHEqev7Qa7lYHAAg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAg) and [Mastering Blender, p190](http://books.google.nl/books?id=Iighl2bcGS0C&pg=PA192&lpg=PA192&dq=guido+van+rossum+eric+idle#v=onepage&q=guido%20van%20rossum%20eric%20idle&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

It's no coincidence.  The creator of the language (and the IDE), Guido van Rossum, is a big Monty Python fan :)

Comment: Note that it is also traditional in Python that examples use `spam` as a generic rather than `foo` or `bar` and any other (Monty) Python based names that the author can squeeze in.

Answer (score 3):

> `*`IDLE is officially a corruption of IDE, but it's really named in honour of Monty Python member Eric Idle.

Marc Lutz, Learning Python 3rd ed., footnote on p50

Comment: 'IDLE' has officially been 'de-corrupted', with Guido's approval, to stand for Integrated Development and Learning Environment. The doc's and SO `python-idle` blurb have been changed to match.